# Firefox add-on pageMod, catch ajax done in contentScriptFile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

my problem is that i need to know when AJAX is done on the page. I need to know this in my contentScriptFile that i load through pageMod. My add on needs to run every time that the page has been modified: so basically when it loads and every time there is an AJAX call.

i tried this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
     alert("AJAX call completed");
});
```

but it does not work.

is there a way to do this?

edit: my page mod code from main.js:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
     include: "*",
     contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-1.9.1.min.js"), 
     self.data.url("script.js")],

     onAttach: function(worker){

      var apiKey = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs.apiKey;
      var ignoreList = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs.ignoreList;

      worker.port.emit("prefSet", [ignoreList, apiKey]);

      }

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure of a jQuery method, but would you like the XPCOM method which listens to all HTTP requests in the browser, and then you can test if the `loadContext` of the HTTP request is the `window` of your `contentScriptFile`.

Comment: @Noitidart i am open to any method that would work:) so if you can please provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this not in a content script:
Im not sure how you will identify the content window of the script. I dont know sdk so well. But see the area `CONTENT_WINDOW_OF_CONTENT_SCRIPT`

```
const { Ci, Cu, Cc, Cr } = require('chrome'); //const {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, classes: Cc, results: Cr } = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');

var observers = {
    'http-on-modify-request': {
        observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            console.info('http-on-modify-request: aSubject = ' + aSubject + ' | aTopic = ' + aTopic + ' | aData = ' + aData);
            var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            var requestUrl = httpChannel.URI.spec
            var goodies = loadContextAndGoodies(aSubject, true);
            if (goodies.contentWindow) {
               if (goodies.contentWindow == CONTENT_WINDOW_OF_CONTENT_SCRIPT) {
                    //do something here
               }
            }
        },
        reg: function () {
            Services.obs.addObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request', false);
        },
        unreg: function () {
            Services.obs.removeObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request');
        }
    }
};
```

Then in that same scope add in this helper function:

```
function loadContextAndGoodies(request, return_goodies) {
  var loadContext = null;

  if (request instanceof Ci.nsIRequest) {
      try {
          if (request.loadGroup && request.loadGroup.notificationCallbacks) {
              loadContext = request.loadGroup.notificationCallbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsILoadContext);
          }
      } catch (ex) {
        console.exception('request loadGroup with notificationCallbacks but oculd not get nsIloadContext', ex);
      }
      if (!loadContext) {
        try {
            if (request.notificationCallbacks) {
                loadContext = request.notificationCallbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsILoadContext);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
          console.exception('request has notificationCallbacks but could not get nsILoadContext', ex);
          /* start - noit's backup try, it might be redundant (im not sure) as Wladamir Palant didn't have this way*/
          try {
            var interfaceRequestor = httpChannel.notificationCallbacks.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor);
            loadContext = interfaceRequestor.getInterface(Ci.nsILoadContext);
          } catch (ex) {
            console.exception('backup method failed:' ex);
          }
          /* end - my backup try, it might be redundant as Wladamir Palant didn't have this way*/
        }
      }
  } else {
    console.warn('request argument is not instance of nsIRequest')
  }

  if (return_goodies) {
    if (!loadContext) {
      return null;
    }

    var contentWindow = loadContext.associatedWindow;
    var DOMWindow = contentWindow.top.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                                     .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
                                     .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                                     .rootTreeItem
                                     .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                                     .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
    var gBrowser = DOMWindow.gBrowser;
    if (gBrowser) {
      var tab = gBrowser._getTabForContentWindow(contentWindow.top);
      var browser = tab.linkedBrowser;
    } else {
      var tab, browser = null;
    }
    var goodies = {
      loadContext: loadContext,
      DOMWindow: DOMWindow,
      gBrowser: gBrowser,
      contentWindow: contentWindow,
      browser: browser,
      tab: tab
    };

    return goodies;
  } else {
    return loadContext;
  }
}
```

### To start observing

To start start obseving all requests do this (for example on startup of your addon)

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].reg();
}
```

### To stop observing

Its important to stop observring (make sure to run this at least on shutdown of addon, you dont want to leave the observer registered for memory reasons)

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].unreg();
}
```

Comment: this is an excellent example, Thank You! a question though: even when i comment out the `CONTENT_WINDOW_OF_CONTENT_SCRIPT` if statement, I still cant get any response from the code. should i put the code inside the pageMod or just completely outside somewhere in main.js?

Comment: Oh crap i forgot to give you the code that adds the observer. All of this code should be outside of pagemod. So it should be anywhere in main.js. I just edited in how to start observing and stop observing.

Comment: this line `Services.obs.addObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request', false);` return an error `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE` `filename = undefined` if u could point ou twhat i did wrong? Thank You

Comment: Thank You very much for your help! I managed to write my own function using your example:)

Comment: Awesome man please link/share ofr others future reference. More hte merrier!