# Trouble Writing Firefox Add on (Registering Observers, Javascript)

Tags: http, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am writing an add-on for firefox but I seem to have a few issues with the channel. I am trying to write a program that receives a websites certificate information and saves it in a specific format. It does not pick up the information I need. 
Heres my code:(Sorry for putting a lot there, but its all essential.)

```
 const {Cc,Ci,Cu} = require("chrome");

 let console = (Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm", {})).console;
 console.log("Importing console.\n");

 // Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

this._loadHandler = function(e) {myExtension.onPageLoad(e); };

var utils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var gBrowser = utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().getBrowser();

gBrowser.addEventListener("load", this._loadHandler, true);

// We register an observer on page load, through page load event listener. Is this round-about?
//  Can we register it directly?

var myExtension = {

onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event
var i = 0;
console.log("Page has been loaded.\n");
this.registerObserver("http-on-examine-response");
this.initialized = true;
},

onPageUnload: function(aEvent) {
    console.log("Page has been unloaded.\n");
    this.unregisterObserver("http-on-examine-response");
},

registerObserver: function(topic) {
var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
.getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(this, topic, false);
console.log("Observer Registered.\n");
},

unregisterObserver: function(topic) {
var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
.getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
observerService.removeObserver(this, topic);
console.log("Observer Unregistered.\n");
},

//Observation Function
observe: function(channel, topic, data) {
console.log("Running Observe....\n");
this.examine_cert(channel);
},

examine_cert: function(channel) {
channel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
//Assigns the channel of the http resource in the host port
var host = channel.URI.hostPort;
//Checks for security info
var si = channel.securityInfo;
if (!si){
    console.log("No securityInfo for "+ host +" , returning\n");
    return;
}

//Gets Certificates status
si.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatusProvider);
var st = si.SSLStatus;
if (!st){
    console.log(st + "\n");
    console.log("No SSLStatus for "+ host +" , returning\n");
    return; 
}

st.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatus);
var cert = st.serverCert;

if (!cert){
    console.log("No serverCert for "+ host +" , returning\n");
    return;
}

// by now we must have a non-empty cert, print it and the status
console.log( "status: " + st + "\n");
console.log( "cert  : " + cert.commonName + "\n");

//certobj.ciphername = st.cipherName;  // apparently, parsed out of cert when SSLStatus is made
//certobj.keyLength = st.keyLength;
//certobj.secretKeyLength = st.secretKeyLength;
},

// Recursively descend into the object, looking for displayName matching re;
//   also, validate objects as we go.
findASN1Object: function (struc, re) {
    if (!struc){
        console.log("\nCertificate does not have a valid structure.\n");
        return;
    }

// Shortcut: object with displayName matching re found, return it immediately
    if (re.test(struc.displayName)) return struc;

    var s = Ci;
    try {
        s = struc.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIASN1Sequence);
    }
    catch (e) {
    console.log("\nCertificate failed nsIASN1Sequence conversion\n");
}

    if ( !s || ! s.isValidContainer) {
        console.log("\nCertificate does not have a valid container.\n");
        return;
    }

// check all the objects recursively
    for (var i=0; i<s.ASN1Objects.length; i++) {
        struc = s.ASN1Objects.queryElementAt(i, Ci.nsIASN1Object);
        var res = this.findASN1Object(struc, re);
        if (res) return res;
    }
},

//------ Object containment:
//   nsIHttpChannel > securityInfo (nsISSLStatusProvider) > SSLStatus (nsISSLStatus) > serverCert (nsIX509Cert) 


fillCertObj: function(obj, cert) {
    obj.cert = cert;
    console.log("\nCert:" + cert + "\n");
    obj.notBefore = cert.validity.notBefore;
    obj.notAfter = cert.validity.notAfter;
    if (cert.issuer) {
        obj.issuerMd5Fingerprint = cert.issuer.md5Fingerprint;
        obj.issuerSha1Fingerprint = cert.issuer.sha1Fingerprint;
    } 
else {
        //console.log("no issuer: "+ [cert.commonName, cert.issuer, cert.sha1Fingerprint]); \
    console.log("\nThe Certificate doesn't have an Issuer.\n");
    }

    var keys = ["commonName", "organization", "organizationalUnit", "serialNumber","emailAddress",
                "issuerCommonName", "issuerOrganization", "issuerOrganizationUnit","md5Fingerprint", "sha1Fingerprint" ];

    for (var i in keys){
        obj[keys[i]] = cert[keys[i]];
    }

    obj.subjectAltName = [];

    var san = this.findASN1Object(cert.ASN1Structure, /^Certificate Subject Alt Name$/);
    if (san) {
        //this.log("SAN:", [san.displayName, san.displayValue]); 

        var m, re = /DNS Name: ((?:\*\.)?[a-z0-9.-]+)/g;
    //                       *.smth1.smth2.smth3....smthn where smth has only a-z,0-9,or -   or
    //                       smth1.smth2.smth3....smthn where smth has only a-z,0-9,or -  

    // push domain names contained in displayValue onto the list subjectAltName
    while (m = re.exec(san.displayValue))
    obj.subjectAltName.push(m[1]);
    }
console.log("Filled Certificate.\n");
},

init_cert: function(){ 
var certobj = this.newCertObj();
//certobj.host = host;
//certobj.ciphername = st.cipherName;
//certobj.keyLength = st.keyLength;
//certobj.secretKeyLength = st.secretKeyLength;
//this.fillCertObj(certobj.now, cert);
console.log(certobj);
},

newCertObj: function() { 
console.log("Creating Empty Certificate.\n");
    return {
    flags: 0,
    host: "",
    warn: {},
    now: {
            commonName: "",
        organization: "",
        organizationalUnit: "",
        serialNumber: "",
        emailAddress: "",
        notBefore: "",
        notAfter: "",
        issuerCommonName: "",
        issuerOrganization: "",
        issuerOrganizationUnit: "",
        md5Fingerprint: "",
        sha1Fingerprint: "",
        issuerMd5Fingerprint: "",
        issuerSha1Fingerprint: "",
        cert: null,
        },
    old: {
            commonName: "",
        organization: "",
        organizationalUnit: "",
        serialNumber: "",
        emailAddress: "",
        notBefore: "",
        notAfter: "",
        issuerCommonName: "",
        issuerOrganization: "",
        issuerOrganizationUnit: "",
        md5Fingerprint: "",
        sha1Fingerprint: "",
        issuerMd5Fingerprint: "",
        issuerSha1Fingerprint: "",
        cert: null,
        },
    };
},
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not wise to register and unregister observer on page load because it will be catching http requests from everywhere. So register it on startup of addon and unregister it on shutdown/unload of addon.

And you should check the loadContext to see for what window/tab/frame/ajax/background is making the request. See here for more on loadContext: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25223307/1828637

But anyways this should work the way you have it meaning reg on page load and unreg on page unload:

```
 const {
    Cc, Ci, Cu
 } = require("chrome");

 let console = (Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm", {})).console;
 console.log("Importing console.\n");

 // Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
 Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

 this._loadHandler = function(e) {
    myExtension.onPageLoad(e);
 };

 var utils = require('sdk/window/utils');
 var gBrowser = utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().getBrowser();

 gBrowser.addEventListener("load", this._loadHandler, true);

 // We register an observer on page load, through page load event listener. Is this round-about?
 //  Can we register it directly?

 var myExtension = {

    observers: {
        'http-on-examine-response': {
            observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
                console.log("Running Observe....\n");
                myExtension.examine_cert(aSubject);

            },
            reg: function() {
                Services.obs.addObserver(myExtension.observers['http-on-examine-response'], 'http-on-examine-response', false);
            },
            unreg: function() {
                Services.obs.removeObserver(myExtension.observers['http-on-examine-response'], 'http-on-examine-response');
            }
        }
    },

    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event
        var i = 0;
        console.log("Page has been loaded.\n");
        myExtension.observers['http-on-examine-response'].reg();
        this.initialized = true;
    },

    onPageUnload: function(aEvent) {
        console.log("Page has been unloaded.\n");
        myExtension.observers['http-on-examine-response'].unreg();
    },

    examine_cert: function(channel) {
        channel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
        //Assigns the channel of the http resource in the host port
        var host = channel.URI.hostPort;
        //Checks for security info
        var si = channel.securityInfo;
        if (!si) {
            console.log("No securityInfo for " + host + " , returning\n");
            return;
        }

        //Gets Certificates status
        si.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatusProvider);
        var st = si.SSLStatus;
        if (!st) {
            console.log(st + "\n");
            console.log("No SSLStatus for " + host + " , returning\n");
            return;
        }

        st.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatus);
        var cert = st.serverCert;

        if (!cert) {
            console.log("No serverCert for " + host + " , returning\n");
            return;
        }

        // by now we must have a non-empty cert, print it and the status
        console.log("status: " + st + "\n");
        console.log("cert  : " + cert.commonName + "\n");

        //certobj.ciphername = st.cipherName;  // apparently, parsed out of cert when SSLStatus is made
        //certobj.keyLength = st.keyLength;
        //certobj.secretKeyLength = st.secretKeyLength;
    },

    // Recursively descend into the object, looking for displayName matching re;
    //   also, validate objects as we go.
    findASN1Object: function(struc, re) {
        if (!struc) {
            console.log("\nCertificate does not have a valid structure.\n");
            return;
        }

        // Shortcut: object with displayName matching re found, return it immediately
        if (re.test(struc.displayName)) return struc;

        var s = Ci;
        try {
            s = struc.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIASN1Sequence);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("\nCertificate failed nsIASN1Sequence conversion\n");
        }

        if (!s || !s.isValidContainer) {
            console.log("\nCertificate does not have a valid container.\n");
            return;
        }

        // check all the objects recursively
        for (var i = 0; i < s.ASN1Objects.length; i++) {
            struc = s.ASN1Objects.queryElementAt(i, Ci.nsIASN1Object);
            var res = this.findASN1Object(struc, re);
            if (res) return res;
        }
    },

    //------ Object containment:
    //   nsIHttpChannel > securityInfo (nsISSLStatusProvider) > SSLStatus (nsISSLStatus) > serverCert (nsIX509Cert) 


    fillCertObj: function(obj, cert) {
        obj.cert = cert;
        console.log("\nCert:" + cert + "\n");
        obj.notBefore = cert.validity.notBefore;
        obj.notAfter = cert.validity.notAfter;
        if (cert.issuer) {
            obj.issuerMd5Fingerprint = cert.issuer.md5Fingerprint;
            obj.issuerSha1Fingerprint = cert.issuer.sha1Fingerprint;
        } else {
            //console.log("no issuer: "+ [cert.commonName, cert.issuer, cert.sha1Fingerprint]); \
            console.log("\nThe Certificate doesn't have an Issuer.\n");
        }

        var keys = ["commonName", "organization", "organizationalUnit", "serialNumber", "emailAddress",
            "issuerCommonName", "issuerOrganization", "issuerOrganizationUnit", "md5Fingerprint", "sha1Fingerprint"
        ];

        for (var i in keys) {
            obj[keys[i]] = cert[keys[i]];
        }

        obj.subjectAltName = [];

        var san = this.findASN1Object(cert.ASN1Structure, /^Certificate Subject Alt Name$/);
        if (san) {
            //this.log("SAN:", [san.displayName, san.displayValue]); 

            var m, re = /DNS Name: ((?:\*\.)?[a-z0-9.-]+)/g;
            //                       *.smth1.smth2.smth3....smthn where smth has only a-z,0-9,or -   or
            //                       smth1.smth2.smth3....smthn where smth has only a-z,0-9,or -  

            // push domain names contained in displayValue onto the list subjectAltName
            while (m = re.exec(san.displayValue))
                obj.subjectAltName.push(m[1]);
        }
        console.log("Filled Certificate.\n");
    },

    init_cert: function() {
        var certobj = this.newCertObj();
        //certobj.host = host;
        //certobj.ciphername = st.cipherName;
        //certobj.keyLength = st.keyLength;
        //certobj.secretKeyLength = st.secretKeyLength;
        //this.fillCertObj(certobj.now, cert);
        console.log(certobj);
    },

    newCertObj: function() {
        console.log("Creating Empty Certificate.\n");
        return {
            flags: 0,
            host: "",
            warn: {},
            now: {
                commonName: "",
                organization: "",
                organizationalUnit: "",
                serialNumber: "",
                emailAddress: "",
                notBefore: "",
                notAfter: "",
                issuerCommonName: "",
                issuerOrganization: "",
                issuerOrganizationUnit: "",
                md5Fingerprint: "",
                sha1Fingerprint: "",
                issuerMd5Fingerprint: "",
                issuerSha1Fingerprint: "",
                cert: null,
            },
            old: {
                commonName: "",
                organization: "",
                organizationalUnit: "",
                serialNumber: "",
                emailAddress: "",
                notBefore: "",
                notAfter: "",
                issuerCommonName: "",
                issuerOrganization: "",
                issuerOrganizationUnit: "",
                md5Fingerprint: "",
                sha1Fingerprint: "",
                issuerMd5Fingerprint: "",
                issuerSha1Fingerprint: "",
                cert: null,
            },
        };
    },

 }
```

lastly why are you wrapping in the pseudo-class `myExtension`? When doing addon-sdk or bootstrap addons you don't have to do that anymore. It makes things easier so you don't have to track what scope you are in.

Comment: I designed it almost completely from another already made extension called Cert Patrol.
So the function reg is just something that runs when the add-on loads?

Comment: It says that the channel is not defined. What could the problem be?

Comment: Whoops fixed that. I had to pas aSubject not channel in line `myExtension.examine_cert(channel);`

Comment: Sorry but there still are error messages. It has something to do with line 52 (this line- examine_cert: function(channel))
I am not sure what the issue is though.

Comment: Open up browser console Ctrl Shift J and paste what the error is.

Comment: console.error: add-on:   
  Message: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
  Stack:
    resource://jid1-cficsterz6oj5q-at-jetpack/add-on/lib/main.js:52:undefined
console.error: add-on: 
  Message: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
  Stack:
    resource://jid1-cficsterz6oj5q-at-jetpack/add-on/lib/main.js:52:undefined

Comment: Can you compile it to xpi and upload to github or somewhere please so i can test and make it work

Comment: Can you make it an xpi please. Those are raw source files. You should aslo make github account and start using it, it helps a lot for programmer :)